# How to do this sed regular expression

Tags: regex

I have

```
SET A
 B
 C
 D
SET E
 F
 G
 H
```

I need a sed command which returns me subitems of A. Items A and E can be exchanged in the list, so D can be also at end of the string.

Comment: `sed` replaces line-by-line so is not the tool you want here. Consider having a look at `awk` instead, shell scripts or any programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the address part of a sed command to match the region. In this case, starting from a line beginning "SET A" up to a line beginning with SET print those lines that start with a space.

```
$ echo -e "SET A\n B\n C\n D\nSET E\n F\n G\n H\n" | sed -n '/^SET A/,/^SET/{
/^ /p
}'
 B
 C
 D
```

Comment: As I wrote, SET A and SET E can be exchanged in the list. It works, thank you.